# Lion iCal calendar event shows up as grey rather than colour of calendar it belongs to

Tags: macos, icloud, ical

I have an item in iCal that shows in grey rather than the (blue) colour of the calendar it belongs to.

It also has an interrupted border rather than a flawless border.

What does that mean?

Update: It shows up in the correct colour (blue) on the Web interface.

Answer (score 1):

If someone has sent you an invite and you have responded "Maybe", the Event will show up as described.

Comment: I created the event and sent an invite and the response was positive.

Comment: Hmm, that's the only circumstance I've seen what you describe.

Comment: This may sound funny... but have you maybe somehow invited yourself? Because @afragen is right: Grey means - it's an invitation to you, which hasn't been accepted yet.